# Android Studio - Collections.sort(), "Cannot Resolve Symbol 'sort'"?

Tags: java, android-studio, collections

I have imported the class with "import java.util.Collections;"

[image]

but still when using the code "Collections.sort()", it gives me the error

"Cannot Resolve Symbol 'sort'"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your `feedItems_full` is a `List` and that `NearbyItem.Comparators.DISTANCE` really is an implementation of `Comparator`.

If that's already the case then try to restart:

> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

..and/or do a clean build:

> Build -> Clean Project

Answer (score 1):

Found out that this Error occured because this line of code is not placed inside the onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you are working in a package that you named Collections.  Any attempt to use Collections will look at the current package as overriding the java.util version, thereby making the sort method from the original unreachable.

Though this obviously didn't happen with you, I thought it might be pertinent to others.  I reached this page while trying to figure out why I was having this problem.